# How do I vertically align label, input and button?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically align input and label and button( which is inside a div)

How can I achieve this

My present code which is not working is the following

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <label style="display: inline-block;float: left; vertical-align: baseline; position: relative; padding-top :5px">Select File</label>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <input type="text" style="display: inline-block;float: left; vertical-align: baseline">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: baseline;float: left" class="file-upload btn" >
            Browse
            <input class="required file-upload-input" type="file">
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should try to apply the vertical-align on the tr...

Comment: try vertical-align: 50%; (or middle). Also, your HTML is invalid, and you can (should) do this without tables, just divs

Comment: If you remove the vertical-align, and instead add top:3px on the labels you can achieve the middle positioning. Valid table format is `<table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>` you can sometimes get away with doing the half job you present here but don't be surprised if the browser doesn't render things they way you wish it to.

Comment: `<td valign="middle">` should work

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're confusing `tr`'s with `td`'s. You should use only one `tr` (table row), and place your elements inside a `td` (table cell) each.

Then, get rid of the divs, and get rid of the inline styles you set to the elements... A `td` is able to use `vertical-align` property, which should be set to `middle`, if you expect the align effect.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <label>Select File</label>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <input class="required file-upload-input" type="file" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<table>
    <tr vertical-align="middle">
        <td>
        <label style="display: inline-block;float: left; position: relative; padding-top :5px">
            Select File
        </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="display: inline-block;float: left; vertical-align: baseline">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr vertical-align="middle">
        <td>
            <div style="display: inline-block; float: left" class="file-upload btn"  >
                Browse
                <input class="required file-upload-input" type="file">
            </div>
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You also missed  tags in rows

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work it displays every tr on a different line

Comment: @user3779089: can you create a Fiddle and tell exactly what you want?

Comment: I think you meant `<tr style="vertical-align: middle;">`